# put eq() of each panel in the title

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">--Here should say 1--</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">--Here should say 2--</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content
  </div>
</div>
```

the following should put if its the 1'st 2'nd 3'rd... panel in the panel header

```
$(".panel .panel-heading").append($(this).eq());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.html()` followed by function like below :

```
$('.panel-heading').html( function ( i, old ) {
   return ( i + 1 );
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/zpe5z4ty/)

Did't fully understand what this statement mean `the following should put if its the 1'st 2'nd 3'rd`, is it you want to put the content only for `panel` element `1st, 2nd and 3rd` only even exist more than that? If that's the case :

```
$('.panel-heading').html( function ( i, old ) { 
  if ( i < 3 )  return ( i + 1 );  
});
```

Comment: That's clean... +1

Comment: Same goes to you mate +1

Comment: I meant all even more then 3. Thanks both of you

Comment: Then stick to first approach stated above, anyway you're welcome mate

Answer (score 3):

You need to use jquery `each` along with the `index()` function with of the panel heading element within the panel heading list.

Elements indexes start from 0 so you need to add 1 to it to view proper numbering:

```js
$(".panel .panel-heading").each(function(){
  
  $(this).append($(this).index('.panel-heading') + 1);
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading"></div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading"></div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.panel .panel-heading').each(function(k,v){ $(v).text(k); });
// or if you want to start from 1:
$('.panel .panel-heading').each(function(k,v){ $(v).text(k + 1); });
```